# How to import JSON from Storage Folder in VUE using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-storage

I'm looking for a much cleaner way than this:

```
<script>
   import list from '../../../../../../../storage/app/public/json/listofcuisines_en.json';
   export default {}
</script>
```

How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use webpack resolve in `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
       alias: {
           "@": path.resolve(
               __dirname,
               "your_path_to_source_folder"
           )
       }
    }
});
```

and then in component

```
<script>
   import list from '@/storage/app/public/json/listofcuisines_en.json';
   export default {}
</script>
```

Comment: what is "your_path_to_source_folder" in case of the standard laravel installation?